# facebook access token still valid after logout

Tags: facebook, curl, token, logout

I am using the Facebook API with libCurl. I tried to logout the user using the logout.php page but the access token is still valid and I can access user data.
I could reproduce this in a browser:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&response_type=token&scope=email

I login to my application and retrieve user data using the open graph with the "me" object:

"https:"//graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN 
(Quotes just because I can't post any more hyperlinks.)

I get a .js file with the data. So far OK.

Now I want to logout the user:
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&next=http://www.google.com

I get redirected to google.com, but I can still retrieve the user data using the me-URL with the access token.

So the access token hasn't become invalid which means that there was no logout!
Am I seeing this wrong? What can be done to invalidate the access token on logout?

Thank you!

Fabian

Comment: You are getting the token using a browser and then try to log out the user using the browser or using curl?

Comment: I do both requests with the browser

Comment: Can you use the facebook js sdk?

Comment: No, using the js sdk is not an option, because we want to connect a C++ app with facebook.

Comment: From my experience the logout method of the js sdk works the best from all the other alternatives. If you are already using a browser for login/logout then why can't you use the jsk for logging out the user?

Comment: I don't want to use a browser. I determined this issue using libcurl and could even reproduce it using a webbrowser.

Comment: But you can't get a user access token with libcurl. You need to use one of the facebook authentication flows (server, client, ios or android)

Comment: Yes, I am using the client authentication flow. I am using the browser only the first time where the user has to register my application. Then I use Curl to get some user data. After that, I want to logout the user from my application.

Comment: Well, as far as I'm aware that's the only option you have then, and it's not working that well. If you can somehow manage to use the js sdk then it's the best option, otherwise the best I can recommend you is to follow the bug reports regarding the logout functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the token should remain valid.
Users logged-in status and the access token are not related.
Token becomes invalid after some timeout or after the user changes their password.